# Highcharts - Automatic min/max range is not set correctly for 'area' and 'column' fill types

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If I set the type as 'line', min-max ranges are set correctly.

```
chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'line'
},
```

But for area and column types, minx-max are not set automatically. How do I set them automatically?
https://jsfiddle.net/kd8qsbjy/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is due to the `threshold` option:

From API:

> **threshold: number**
>
> The Y axis value to serve as the base for
>   the columns, for distinguishing between values above and below a
>   threshold. If null, the columns extend from the padding Y axis
>   minimum.
>
> Defaults to 0.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        threshold: null
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/180rqmb7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.threshold